# "A recently served boot binary is corrupt"

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps

My Windows 10 said it needs to update, so I restarted it. Instead of restarting, I got the following sequence of screens:

- "Preparing automatic repair"
- "Enter the BitLocker recovery key: " [I entered it]
- "Diagnosing your PC"
- "Your PC did not start correctly. Restart or AdvancedOptions"
- When I click "Restart", the same sequence starts again. So I click "AdvancedOptions" and then "Troubleshoot".

In the troubleshoot screen, I tried the following:

- Remove latest quality update: it failed.
- Remove latest feature update: it failed.
- Run "Startup Repair": I got a message "Startup repair could not repair your PC". It also referred me to a log file called `SrtTrail.txt`.
- I opened the command line, opened the file `SrtTrail.txt` (using notepad), and at the bottom line, I saw the message: `A recently served boot binary is corrupt.`
- I tried `BootRec /FixMBR` - I got `the operation completed successfully`.
- I tried `BootRec /FixBoot` - I got `access is denied`.
- I tried `BootRec /RebuildBCD` - I got `total identified windows installations: 0`.
- I tried `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal` to boot into safemode, but then rebooted and got to the start of the sequence.
- I ran the Dell Preboot System Performance check, as instructed in Dell Website, and after several minutes I got "success: result code 2000-0000", which means that "Pre-boot diagnostics test passed. No issues were found".
- I ran `ChkDsk /r`. It told me that there are no problems with my drive. But I still get the same sequence
- I did `bcdboot c:\windows /s c:`. I got a success message - "boot files created successfully" or something like that. But I still get the same sequence.
- I tried `sfc /scannow` but got an error "windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation".

What more can I do to fix this error?

Technical details: I have Windows 10 on Dell XPS 9570, BIOS version 1.20.0. No other OS is installed.

Comment: Automatic Repair that cannot start or work is often a sign of a bad drive. Get the Dell Hardware Diagnostics on bootable USB and check all the hardware.

Comment: @John I ran the Preboot System Performance check, as instructed [here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-il/000179493/dell-diagnostic-tools-to-diagnose-and-fix-hardware-problems-on-your-dell-pc-tablet-or-servers), and after several minutes I got "success: result code 2000-0000".

Comment: Does the tool you ran tell you what 2000-0000 means?

Comment: @John Dell website says that this code means "Pre-boot diagnostics test passed. No issues were found "

Comment: So you can now start up?

Comment: @John no... I get the same "automatic repair" sequence. I also tried `ChkDsk /r`: it told me that there are no problems with my drive. But I still get the same sequence.

Comment: That means your operating system has been very badly corrupted (since hardware is OK you say). You will need to boot with a bootable USB key, get your data and reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Had success with recreating the Win 10 EFI bootloader.

I know it's an older thread, but for those landing here, here's what worked for me in this situation.  Ran through a very similar series of steps, but also including purchasing the EasyRE repair tool from Neosmart that is associated with EasyBCD.  Didn't work for me.

At http://woshub.com/windows-8-winload-efi-is-missing-or-damaged/ I followed the steps for "Repair BCD and Winload.efi File for UEFI Device" and suddenly it booted!

1. Execute the command: diskpart
2. List the partitions on the disks: list volume
3. Find a partition labeled ESP or EFI with a size of 100 MB. Remember it (the size and name of the partition may differ depending on the version of Windows, but the main thing is that its file system must always be FAT32). If the EFI partition was accidentally deleted, it can be restored as follows;
4. Select this partition: select volume 2
5. Assign a drive letter to the partition: assign letter=Z
6. Exit the diskpart: exit
7. Now you need to re-create the bootloader configuration. Copy the boot files from the Windows directory: bcdboot c:\Windows /s Z: /f ALL (replace c:\ with the drive letter on which you have the Windows installed). If you did everything correctly, the message will appear:  Boot files successfully created;
8. Reboot your device and check if the boot problem with winload.efi file is fixed.

Comment: Yeah this fixed it for me, after trying tons of other stuff. Thanks!

I think this problem may have been caused by an issue with Windows Update, since once I'd rebuilt this EFI partition, Windows booted and there was some message like "The update failed so we're rolling it back".